# Handle Null Values in MVC Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model

I have a problem with my MVC 4 Application. I have a Model with code as follows:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Type")]
    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "")] 
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

The `Code` field in the Model represents a non-nullable type from the database while the `Type` field accepts null values. Now my problem comes when I try to load items from the Model and into my View using my Controller. Please see the following Controller code:

```
public ActionResult Display(string Code)
{
    MyManager manage= new MyManager();

    Model model= new Model();
    model = manage.GetItem(Code);

    MyModel obj = new MyModel();
    obj.Code = model.Code.Trim();
    obj.Type = model.Type.Trim();

    return View(obj);
 }
```

Basically the GetItems method comes from my manager which accepts the `Code` and returns data of type Model (which is the name of the table in my database).

The problem points at this line: `obj.Type = model.Type.Trim();` whenever null values coming from the database occurs.

Can someone please point me to an effective way on how to handle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to check the database return before to copy to ViewModel object.

```
obj.Type = provider.Type != null ? provider.Type.Trim() : string.Empty;
```

Comment: Hi! This one pretty much handles what I needed. Now I have another question, how about if the datatype of the nullable field is `DateTime`? How can I handle it? Thank you very much!

Comment: You'll have to change the database entity to DateTime? datatype. So you can use similar statement or just check `HasValue` property of Nullable before to copy the value to ViewModel object.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
public string? Type { get; set; }
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response! I already tried using `public string? Type {get; set;}` but I get another error message saying: `The type 'string' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable<T>'`. Any idea where this is coming from? Thanks!

Comment: Ahh, I misread your question. System.String is a reference type and already nullable.
Nullable<T> and the ? suffix are for Int32, Double, DateTime and other value-types.